# pandoc to make each directory a chapter

Tags: pandoc

I have a lot of markdown files in various directories each with the same format (# title, then ## sub-title).

can I make the --toc respect the folder layout, in that the folder itself is the name of chapter, and each markdown file is content of this chapter.

so far pandoc totally ignores my folder names, it works the same as putting all the markdown files within the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this is to create index files in each folder with first level heading and downgrade headings in other files by one level.

I use Git and by default I'm using default structure, having first level headings in files, but when I want to generate ebook using `pandoc` I'm modifying files via automated Linux shell script. After that, I revert changed files via Git.

Here's the script:

```bash
find ./docs/*/ -name "*.md" ! -name "*index.md" -exec perl -pi -e "s/^(#)+\s/#$&/g" {} \;
```

`./docs/*/` means I'm looking only for files inside subfolders of `docs` directory like `docs/foo/file1.md`, `docs/bar/file2.md`.

I'm also interested only in `*.md` files, excluding `*index.md` files.

In `index.md` files (that I name usually `00-index.md` to make them appear as first), I put a first level heading `#` and because those files are excluded from *find* portion of the script, their headings aren't downgraded.

Next, there's a perl's search and replace command with regular expression `s/^(#)+\s/#$&/g` that looks for all lines starting from one or more `#` and adds another `#` to them.

In the end, I'm running `pandoc` with `--toc-depth=2` so the table of content contains only first and second level headings.

```bash
pandoc ./docs/**/*.md --verbose --fail-if-warnings --toc-depth=2 --table-of-contents -o ./ebook.epub
```

To revert all changes made to files, I restore changes in the Git repo.

```bash
git restore .
```